# Is there any alternate to acquire dependencies without using POM.xml?

Tags: java, maven, selenium

My question is, I don't want to write XML code for dependencies in the `POM.xml` again and again. 
For example, I want to use the `log4j` JAR in my project. instead of writing XML code is there any option to download the related JAR files?

Comment: You can download the jars but I'm not sure if you can use the in your project without specifying them in pom.xml. I think you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate method is downloading the jars from sites like maven or java2s.com and add them to your build path.
You can add a jar in Eclipse by right-clicking on the **Project → Build Path → Configure Build Path**. Under Libraries tab, click Add Jars or Add External JARs and give the Jar.
Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can download (or copy) these jars, and then manually add them to your build path.
For instance in eclipse, you can select all the libraries under the "Maven Dependiences" and copy them to other folder eg. in other project. Then you need to select these libraries and using the right mouse button add them to build path, done :)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to write them again and again. You can define and install a parent pom with the common dependencies you use and refer to it in each project pom.

Answer (score 0):

First you could download jars you need in your project from corresponding websites.

Next,follow the steps below:

**Step 1**： Create a folder under the project to save the JAR package.We usually store jar packages from the outside in the [lib] folder.

**Step 2**: Copy the jar to the lib folder.

**Step 3**: Right-click on the project name, and select it in turn [Build Path] - > [Configure Build Path...]

**Step 4**: In the open window, select the Libraries page and click on the right button the [add JARs...] then select the jar package we just copied into the project, and then click [OK] to close the window.

Finally, we can use this jar package in Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add them through the java build path from your IDE. However, I would recommend that you add these jars as dependencies in the pom.xml and build your project through maven. This will make sure that you will not run into any error regarding the missing dependencies in case any jar gets deleted accidentally or if you want the same set of jars for a new project. And understanding a pom.xml is not a difficult task

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Thank you for answering this question, but it would be more helpful if you could add examples (ie how to access the java build path, how to add them to the java build path, showing how to add to pom.xml, and building the project through maven).